# PDF.js rendering inccorrect characters with RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, pdf.js

I getting [incorrect characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ0zz.png) when i tried use pdf.js in my app.
My require.config:

```
require.config({paths: {'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf':'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.7.570/pdf.min'});
```

My code like:

```
define("SomeModule", ["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"], function(pdf){
pdf.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.7.570/pdf.worker.min.js';
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: somePdfData});
})
```

When i loaded pdf.js via script before RequireJS was loading - all works fine.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Probably a bug in the library, try creating an issue on the GitHub

Comment: Good idea. Thank you. Create issue https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/13073